# Need help explaining VPS infastructure situation

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, webserver, vps

I'm a fullstack web developer and having difficulties explaining a situation at work regarding VPS servers to my new technical director and was wondering if anyone has any advice.

The technical director wants to move from our current production infrastructure (which hosts about 50 websites) to the following:

1 VPS instance running some sort of VM software (Not sure if this is even possible) to create indivual VPS instances for each of our websites.

Now i know this sounds absolutly crazy but I am really struggling to explain the situation to the person and everytime I try they get really uptight and say's everything I know is basically wrong.

If someone could give me a good explaination of why this is such a bad idea in lamens terms so non technical people higher up could understand clearly the issues.

Sorry if this is posted in the wrong section as I need a technical minded person's answer ironically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your technical director should know all the answers, evidently they are not qualified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your VPS is already running in a VM.  Depending on the hypervisor type it's likely it is not possible due to the way x86 virtualization works (x86 doesn't support "nesting" hypervisors - the hypervisor would have to emulate the x86 virtualization behavior).  IF this is possible it's going to be SLOW.  You want separate VPSes for each of your websites.

Comment: ^^ this.... and then dont do like they did here when i arrived and have all those VPS servers on one single physical server with no clustering. Hard drive thrashing ? Ya think?!